# How to add a 'RAM usage' icon on the panel in LXDE

Tags: 12.04, panel, lxde

I have a **CPU usage** icon on my panel in LXDE in Ubuntu but I also want to monitor my RAM usage as my RAM is only 512 MB

[image: LXDE desktop screenshot]

How can I add an icon to the panel for this purpose?

Comment: [LxTask](http://lxde.org/lxtask_task_manager) shows the RAM usage, but I don't think there is a way to put it on the panel...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if this is god enough for what you want, but here you go.  Right click on the LxPanel, and choose Add / Remove Panel Items

[image]

Click on Add

[image]

Choose Resources Monitor, and then click Add

[image]

While Resources Monitor is still highlighted, click on Edit

[image]

Choose either or both monitors, and click Close

[image]

And this is what you get (sorry the image is not that clear)

[image]

Hope that this answers your question.

Comment: No not really, its stock LXDE on 13.04.

Comment: Is there any way to update the refresh rate or have it show the % all the time? I want to use this to try to anticipate out of memory conditions which freeze my computer...

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `lxpanel` installed? If you do, look for an applet called "Resource Monitors". That one lets you monitor both %CPU usage as well as RAM.

[image: Lxpanel]

Comment: your one was also good but mitch showed all the methods beautifully